# F# child agent. Is there a 'this' pointer

Tags: f#, actor

I have the following pattern - and I am wondering what is the best way to solve it. An agent #1, wants to issue an agent #2 and provide a call-back to itself. Does the agent #1 has some kind of 'this' pointer it can provide to the child agent #2?

One way to solve this is to have some agent registry and for the parent to give its 'id' to the child. I am wondering if there is some more direct way. I post a code snippet below

```
type Agent<'a> = MailboxProcessor<'a>

type A1Message =
    | CreateChild
    | ChildNotification

type A2Message =
    | Start
    | Stop

let a1Ref = ref <| Unchecked.defaultof<Agent<A1Message>>

let a1 =
    Agent<A1Message>.Start(
        fun inbox ->
            async {      
                let a2 = ref <| Unchecked.defaultof<Agent<A2Message>>                      
                while true do
                        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                        match msg with
                        | CreateChild -> 
                            a2 := Agent<A2Message>.Start(
                                        fun inbox ->
                                            async {
                                                while true do
                                                    let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                                                    match msg with
                                                    | Start -> 
                                                        (!a1Ref).Post ChildNotification
                                                    | Stop -> ()
                                            }
                                        )
                            (!a2).Post Start
                        | ChildNotification -> 
                            printfn "Notified by Child"
                            (!a2).Post Stop
            }
        )

do
    a1Ref := a1
```

Comment: Have you thought about refactoring your code?

Comment: How about the ``inbox`` of agent a1? It's available in the child (if you rename ``inbox`` of the child to something else)...

Comment: I suspect part of the OPs reason to post here is to get suggestions on how to refactor the code...

Answer (score 2):

Some might argue that a `this` pointer is not an FP idiom and that there are better patterns for FP.

If the a2 processor needs to post to a1 processor one way to do it could be 
like this:

For example

```
type A1Message =
    | CreateChild
    | ChildNotification of MailboxProcessor<A2Message>

and A2Message =
    | Start
    | Stop

let a1 (inbox : MailboxProcessor<_>) =
    async {      
        printfn "Parent started"
        while true do
                let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                printfn "Parent received: %A" msg
                match msg with
                | CreateChild -> 
                    let childInbox = MailboxProcessor.Start (a2 inbox)
                    childInbox.Post Start
                | ChildNotification childInbox -> 
                    childInbox.Post Stop
    }

let a2 (parentInbox : MailboxProcessor<_>) (inbox : MailboxProcessor<_>) = 
    async {
        printfn "Child started"
        let cont = ref true
        while !cont do
            let! msg = inbox.Receive()
            printfn "Child received: %A" msg
            match msg with
            | Start -> parentInbox.Post <| ChildNotification inbox
            | Stop  ->
                cont := false
        printfn "Child stopped"
    }

open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    printfn "Starting parent"
    let inbox = MailboxProcessor.Start a1

    inbox.Post CreateChild

    ignore <| Console.ReadKey ()

    0
```

1. When creating an a2 processor the a1 processor passes it's inbox to the a2 processor making it easy for a2 processor to post to the a1 processor.
2. The ChildNotification message is modified to carry the inbox for the child processor making it easy for the a1 process to post to the child.

Hopefully this is helpful to you

Comment: All right, this way is pretty straightforward. The parent inbox was the callback I was after. Thx